# How can I call a Play! Framework template without render()?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a JSON template under *app/views/Application/movie.json* in my Play Framework app.

Normally you use render() to access this template, but that requires an request to server. How can I use this template server side and get the JSON output, without doing another request? Is there something like `JsonArray movies = Templates.render("movie.json")`?

Comment: BTW, what do you want to get with this template ? just formatted JSON object ?

Comment: Getting the JSON as String or JsonElement does not matter. Both will work

Comment: Well generally I preffer using Java JSON serializers instead manual 'in-template' JSON rendering – just considering if it wasn't better for you to use ie. `flexjson`, `jackson` or some other similar library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// prepare your template arguments
String s = TemplateLoader.load("Application/movie.json").render(params);
// the string s is the rendered output, you can do further processing 
// to convert it into JSON object
```